# Azure web service updating same docker image every few hours

Tags: azure, docker, web-services, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to build an application with python to **scrape** and serve data.
All data is stored as sqlite3 database in /app/data folder.

Here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.0

WORKDIR /app

COPY './requirements.txt' .

RUN mkdir /app/data
RUN mkdir /app/logs

RUN chmod -R 777 /app/data
RUN chmod -R 777 /app/logs

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "app.py" ]
```

Azure is taking image source from the private docker hub repository.
At first, the application worked fine but after a few hours image got updated(I didn't change anything) and the container got cleared, which means all my data(database/logs) is gone.

Continuous Deployment is set to Off and I'm not updating the image in docker hub.

How I can prevent container rebuilding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Always On turned on in the App Service settings?

Also, the nature of containers makes them ephemeral so you should never store data that you want to keep inside them.  That being said, App Service provides you with an easy way map a volume to the storage included in your App Service.  The feature is called **Persistent Shared Storage** and it maps the **WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME** env variable to the App Service's **/home** folder.

In the Web App's **Application Settings** You need to set **WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE** to **true** and inside your container, you'll now see a **/home** folder.  That folder points to the storage part of your App Service.

Using a Docker Compose file you can also define a volume using that env variable:

```
${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/LogFiles:/app/logs
```

[Link to the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container)

Comment: I'm using azure for students subscription and  "Always On" or service storage is not available with a free tier service. So I have to create my application differently. Thank for your time